# How to highlight lines in Xcode that have been changed

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to get Xcode to highlight or mark the lines in a file that have been changed?  Something like what it does for search results or warnings and errors would be great.

Comment: Changed relative to the file as saved on disk. Just Googled this. Fresh question.

Comment: Yes, changed according to source control.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Click on "Show the version editor" in the toolbar of Xcode. This will show you a side by side view of your current version of the file compared to the file as it was with your previous commit (I am assuming you are using git).

[image: Or: View - >Version Editor -> Show Version Editor (Shift+Option/Alt+CMD+Enter)]

Comment: Apple's been busy since I first asked this question.  The version editor is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPotter it has been busy with the latest Xcode version too removing all the useful plugins :(

Answer (score 5):

There's an Xcode plugin which does exactly this: https://github.com/johnno1962/GitDiff

You can even customise it:

[image]

Comment: Any alternate for the newer Xcode version ? I mean is there any inbuilt extension which is doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not directly in Xcode but to compare to versions of the same file you can use FileMerge. With the modern app bundle type of install you can get to that from Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> FileMerge. Then just nominate a left file and a right file.

If you're talking about versions of a file from one of the supported source control repositories then you can use the version editor — it's one of the options above 'Editor' in the top right of the window or you can find the relevant option in View -> Version Editor -> Show Version Editor. At that point there'll be three options available below the righthand file view (and up in the View -> Version Editor menu), the first of which is a comparison highlighting differences between the current local copy and any of the checked in copies.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I know I can do this outside of Xcode.  What I'm really looking for is this feature within Xcode.

Comment: The source control changes show directly in Xcode — I wasn't explicit about it but the version editor is a built-in view.